# Why doesn't WebApi config for WebHook work on POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ifttt

i want to get posted data from IFTTT from WebHook. It works when using GET but it doesn't when using POST.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("InsertData")]
public IActionResult InsertData([FromBody] string FromAddress)
{
    try
    {
         //var fromAddress = Request.Form["FromAddress"].ToString();
        _webHookDb.UserData.Add(new UserData()
        {  
            FromAddress = FromAddress,
            DateTime = DateTime.Now
        });
        _webHookDb.SaveChanges();
        return new JsonResult(FromAddress);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: "not working" - how? Any error messages? Unexpected behavior? Please explain. Also, we need to see your code.

Comment: thank you for answer.this is my code

Comment: Do you have an example of the webhook payload?

Comment: I do not have for .net core

Comment: @amin Do you know what data is sent by the web hook? You still have not explained what not working means.

Comment: i got error 400 from IFTTT activity log

Comment: condition "if Any new email in inbox(gmail)"  call webhook

Comment: @amin I noticed you have a comment in code about getting data from a form. what content type is the IFTTT sending the data? JSON, form data, XML? What?

Comment: @Nkosi  application/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a model to hold the data

```
public class Model {
    public string FromAddress { get; set; }
}
```

use that in the action endoint.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("InsertData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertData([FromBody] Model model) {
    try {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            _webHookDb.UserData.Add(new UserData() { 
                FromAddress = model.FromAddress,
                DateTime = DateTime.Now
            });
            await _webHookDb.SaveChangesAsync();
            return new Ok(model);
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState); //Bad data?
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message); //Something wrong with my code?
    }
}
```

Review the message returned from the response in the web-hook to get details about why the request failed.

If HTTP Status Code 500 then something is wrong with how the data is being saved.

If HTTP Status Code 400 then something is wrong with how the data is being sent.